# Match string using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have text in a `$abc` variable.

Now I want to check that text can hold only characters `(a-z, A-Z, 0-9)`. If they have any character except those, then "a output" should be returned.

How can I do that?

```
example: $abc = "this is @ text"; // no match
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
$abc = "this is @ text";
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]*\z/i', $abc)) {
  echo 'bad';
}
```

With regards to Jame C's comment, here is the inverted case:

```
$abc = "this is @ text";
if (preg_match('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $abc)) {
  echo 'bad';
}
```

Comment: Why the `*`? Don't you just need one of those chars?

Comment: @James C The intention of the pattern is to match a correct string. What you imply would be the inverted case. For that, the character class would need to be inverted too, like `[^...]` and the negation of the preg_match `!` would have to be removed.
I think it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: ah sorry, I missed the `^` and `$`. Still waiting for the caffeine to kick in today!

Comment: @James C No problem. To be honest, I think your case (the inverted one) should be the one preferred, for I would bet it get's evaluated quicker than my first pattern. ;)

Comment: Just so you know, `"foo\n"` will match in the first case. Don't use `$` when you mean `\z`.

Comment: @Qtax, it can be solved by specifying `D` modifier. Though, it is incompatible with Perl.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( !preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$#', $abc) ) {
    // wrong chars spotted
}
```

Comment: Dunno. +1 from me (though prefer `/i` for brevity).

Comment: `i` is matter of taste. Sometimes it can be excluded to ensure that someone who reads the code can see that both upper and lower case characters are accepted (`i` is a bit harder to notice).

Comment: I downvoted because second parameter was missing. upping back

Comment: @Arda, downvotes should be given only for completely wrong answers. If there's some typo or missing argument, just tell about it in comment (or edit the post to improve it).

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to evaluate

```
preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $myString)
```

if you don't mind spaces and underscores being in there too then you could use this:

```
preg_match('/\W/', $myString)
```

Comment: Second pattern seems to be wrong. To select non-word character, use `\W` (upper case "W"). If talking about underscores and spaces, `\w` includes underscore, but not space.

Comment: hello,when iuse any special charecter except those on ino al the last then the value shows ok..how to solve it

Comment: sorry, I can't understand the question